# Control rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an app like pulse app, an horizaontal tableview. I want to show 5 rows in a section but i want to control the width of the row when it is in landscape or portrait, so it adjust to the screen. how can i do this is there a method to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resize your UITableView when the device is rotated. Something like this:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    //Resize your UITableView, i.e.:
    orientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        myTable.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    }
    else
    {
        myTable.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    }

    [[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```